Could the Dream Chaser be launched to the ISS with a Falcon 9 rocket?
It seems to be the ultimate marriage of 2 reusable systems.
It pains me to watch people struggle with old-style parachute recovery capsules and disposable rockets.
The combination of the two would be a realization of the X-20 DynaSoar program of the early 1960s with a recoverable booster as well.
Is there any reason why this flexible "mini Shuttle" system could not be the most economical way of re-supplying present and future orbiting stations?

A capsule maybe isn't as glamorous as a spaceplane but at the moment it is still the safest method for getting people to and from space, primarily because of its ability to handle an abort in virtually any phase of launch, the ability to land in water if necessary in an abort, and even has the potential of surviving an instantaneous booster failure. It is not a sign of technical backwardness to still be using a capsule and parachutes, it's a sign that spaceplanes have not yet been fully proven in terms of safety in all phases of launch, although they may eventually be.

@StevePemberton The boosters have come a long way. Keep in mind airliners do (3 degree) powered landings too, because their propulsion systems have become extremely (redundant and) reliable.  And the DreamChaser is, well, a glider.

RobertDiGiovanni - there is absolutely no comparison between airliner reliability and risk and orbital launch vehicles, not to mention the difference in power involved. The airline fatality rate in the U.S. is currently running at about 1 in 20 million flights. Even if booster reliability was 1 failure in 1,000 which would be considered a good record that would still be 20,000 times more dangerous than flying on an airliner. Yes airline fatality rates used to be higher, and in the future rocket reliability will be better, but we are talking about the present time.

@StevePemberton I'm talking about the future.  Wouldn't reliable powered landings (for Earth and other heavenly bodies) be a worthy goal?

RobertDiGiovanni - I never said anything about it not being a worthy goal, but your question reads at least to me as being about the present, not about what might happen a decade or more in the future. Dream Chaser cargo version will add data for the remainder of this decade, including the economic point that you raised. And Starship will provide let's just say some interesting data about alternatives to capsules because it's too early to know how economical it will be for something like space station resupply.

@StevePemberton yes, we'll see how Starship does with re-entry.

Starship seemed to handle reentry pretty well generally speaking. But I didn't say anything about reentry, I am talking only about launch. I think in general spaceplanes can probably be made to be as safe as capsules for reentry and landing. I think Dream Chaser for example would make a great space station lifeboat. Sierra Space does say that it can abort at any phase of launch including pad abort, which sounds promising, but remains to be proven. And even if it does prove safe the next question is can the concept be scaled up and still have the same abort capability.

SierraSpace Dream Chaser is designed to be launch vehicle agnostic. In fact, the Dream Chaser spacecraft itself probably wouldn't even need to be modified, since it is only the Shooting Star service module that is physically mated to the launch vehicle, as far as I know.
One possible problem is that I am not 100% sure Dream Chaser will fit into the standard-size Falcon 9 fairing. SpaceX has committed to develop a larger fairing, but that fairing is currently only planned for Falcon Heavy. It is also not reusable.

The combination of the two would be a realization of the X-20 DynaSoar program of the early 1960s with a recoverable booster as well.

Except it wouldn't be reusable. Dream Chaser is way too heavy to be able to recover Falcon 9. In fact, it is pushing the limits even of a fully expended Falcon 9. It requires a Vulcan Centaur VC4L with four GEM 63XL strap-on solid rocket boosters, which is the second-most powerful version of Vulcan Centaur. Ariane 5 was also in the running at one point. Both vehicles are more powerful than a reusable Falcon 9.
But all of that is moot, since NASA is unlikely to allow Dream Chaser to launch on Falcon 9. The whole point of having multiple providers for the CRS-2 contract, is dissimilar redundancy: multiple independent systems that share no common parts.
And I don't see any other customers other than NASA needing cargo resupply to the USOS of the ISS anytime soon.
SierraSpace is, however, cooperating with Blue Origin on Orbital Reef, and the official render shows both Dream Chaser and Starliner docked, so it is entirely conceivable that Dream Chaser might launch to this station on New Glenn. However, their relationship has turned somewhat cold recently, as both companies want to focus their energy on New Glenn and Dream Chaser, respectively.
There a number of other commercial space stations being proposed, both within NASA's Commercial LEO Destinations program and independent of it, and several of those have shown official or semi-official renders with Dream Chaser.

You say it is too large to launch on a reusable Falcon 9, as well as the fact that the larger fairing is only planned for use in Falcon Heavy. That leads to the follow-up of “would Dream Chaser be able to launch on a Falcon Heavy in a reusable configuration?”

@fyrepenguin and more importantly would it be economical to do so compared to a dragon launch, especially now that spacex has abandoned attempts to recover the falcon heavy centre core

Ah, hadn’t thought about that, @AlanBirtles but I wasn’t sure if they’d abandoned that completely or just not had the opportunity due to the payloads requiring more performance than would make sense for recovery.

@fyrepenguin I'm not sure they've explicitly said they'll never do it again but there's not much performance difference between a fully expended falcon 9 and a fully recovered falcon heavy so it doesn't make much sense

Ah, so now we're at building the Falcon 10 or launching a larger Dream Chaser on the Heavy.  This is 2024!  Do we still fly 1860s, er, 1960s designs?

@AlanBirtles - last year Jon Edwards
the head of Falcon launches for SpaceX said "Next few Heavy missions all require we expend the center core, but should have at least one mission next year where we recover it (Astrobotic Griffin)."

@RobertDiGiovanni: "Do we still fly 1860s, er, 1960s designs?" – I don't know who "we" is (I don't fly rockets), but some do. One of the "features" that allowed SpaceX to get the Falcon 9 developed relatively quickly and cheaply, for example, is that there is nothing "fancy" about it. The Merlin engine, for example, is an open-cycle fuel-rich gas-generator engine, same cycle as the F-1 engine on the Saturn V. So, literally every single Falcon 9 or Falcon Heavy launch is using "1960s designs".

@JörgWMittag yes, and the wheel is good too.  I was referring to disposable rockets and parachute capsules.  DreamChaser seems to have it right with a separate cargo module.  The Shuttle was limited by the dimensions of its cargo bay.  Great for bringing something back from space, though.
